# svn diff with vim, but with the proper filetype

Tags: svn, vim, file-type

[This blog post](http://blog.tplus1.com/index.php/2007/08/29/how-to-use-vimdiff-as-the-subversion-diff-tool/) gives a simple way to use Vim with `svn diff`. Unfortunately, Vim doesn't understand the left-hand-side filetype so there's no syntax highlighting. What's the simplest/best way of solving this?

Comment: what is the filetype of the left-hand file? can you find a syntax file for it at vim.org?

Comment: screenshot? or at least the file names?

Comment: e.g:
it's as if vimdiff was invoked with the following command
vimdiff .svn/text-base/foo.php.svn-base foo.php

so you see, vim fails to recognize the filetype of the lhs file as php because of the different extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I use restructured text within a file with the .txt suffix, by default, vim won't highlight the text.  So I put this at the top of my file:

```
.. vim: set filetype=rst :
```

And then vim does all the cute syntax highlighting.

Try adding a modeline to the first line of your files and then see if vim does what you want when you do a diff.

Incidentally, that's my blog you linked to!  Can I get a prize?

Comment: This works too, thanks Matthew.
The solution given by "too much php" works of course, but I think this is a good practice and is independent of the file extension.

Answer (score 8):

Add the following code to `~/.vim/filetype.vim`:

```
" only load filetypes once
if exists("did_load_filetypes")
  finish
endif

augroup filetypedetect

" when BufRead or BufNewFile event is triggered, pop off the .svn-base extension and
" manually restart filetype autocommands
autocmd! BufRead    *.svn-base execute 'doautocmd filetypedetect BufRead ' . expand('%:r')
autocmd! BufNewFile *.svn-base execute 'doautocmd filetypedetect BufNewFile ' . expand('%:r')

augroup END
```

As the comments state, this code will pick up `.svn-base` files and try to figure out what the filetype would be without that extension on the end.

```
:help new-filetype
:help :doautocmd
:help expand()
```

Answer (score 0):

a quick search for "vim set filetype" gave me [this link](http://www.build-doctor.com/2008/06/04/how-to-set-the-filetype-in-vim-when-the-extension-doesnt-match/), which shows you how to make this work "forever" by changing .vimrc a bit.
If you're just stuck with a file for once, and you know its "correct" filetype, you can try (from the left hand side file):

```
:set filetype=XXX
```

where **XXX** is the appropriate format (e.g. python, c, etc)

a look at

```
:help filteype
```

might also help a bit

Comment: I'm afraid not. The filetype of the left-hand-side file will <rhs-filename.svn-base>, i.e. it is dependent on the right-hand-side filename.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I suggested you "force vim's hand" into understanding the left hand side is a different filetype.

I did this:
echo "import time" > 1.py
echo "import time" > 2.cpp

now on left handside typing 
:set filetype 
shows:
filetype=python

on rhs it shows:
filetype=cpp

but I can force the rhs by using:
:set filetype=python

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> it's as if vimdiff was invoked with the following command `vimdiff .svn/text-base/foo.php.svn-base foo.php` so you see, vim fails to recognize the filetype of the lhs file as php because of the different extension.

No proper solution is known to me. I use something like this in different scenario, but that only *fixes* the syntax highlighting:

```
au BufReadPost *.php.svn-base       set syntax=php
```

You can also try that:

```
au FileType *.php.svn-base          set filetype=php
```

but I can't test that as I have `:filetype` disabled. That should overwrite file type detection for the `.php.svn-base` files and map it to the desired `php`. I have checked that it overrides the `'filetype'` and `'syntax'`: `:set filetype?` and `:set syntax?` produce expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Building on too much php's answer, this works even when the file extension is not in the svn filename. Assuming you run vimdiff with svn-base as the first argument and the working copy as the second:

```
autocmd! BufRead *.svn-base if &diff && argc() == 2 |
    \     execute 'doautocmd filetypedetect BufRead '.argv(1) |
    \ endif
autocmd! BufNewFile *.svn-base if &diff && argc() == 2 |
    \     execute 'doautocmd filetypedetect BufNewFile '.argv(1) |
    \ endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [GVim 8.0 as the Diff Viewer for TortoiseSVN 1.9.7 on Windows 10](http://kun-hong.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/gvim-diff-mode-integration-with-svn-on.html), I found that the GVim recognises the php file extension correctly and displayed the syntax highlighting perfectly.